# Encontrar fila y columna de una matriz a partir de una posicion

Tags: java

necesito encontrar una posición en una matriz de 16x12 a partir de un número generado aleatoriamente, y nose cómo hacerlo exactamente. Os dejo el código:

```
int nFil = 16;
int nCol = 12;
int [][] matriz = new int[nFil][nCol];
int numCeldas = nFil * nCol;
for (int i = 0; i < numObstaculos; i++) {
    int pos = r.nextInt(numCeldas); //Genero la posicion 

    int fila, columna; //Esto es lo que no sé calcular

    //PARA CONTROLAR QUE NO SE REPITAN CELDAS
    //Mientras haya obstaculo en el numero generado, cambio de numero
    while (campoBatalla[fila][columna] = 1) { //Aqui necesito poner la fila y la columna de la posicion generada aleatoriamente

    }       
}

return matriz;
```

Comment: Si generas una posición aleatoriamente entre `0` y `191`, posiblemente se lance la excepción `ArrayIndexOutBounds`. Por que las posiciones válidas en cuestión de filas es de: `0` a `15` y de columnas: `0` a `11`. La forma como lo deberías hacer (desde mi opinión) es primero generar una posición de manera aleatoria para `nFila` y después para `nCol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes aplicar estas dos sencillas fórmulas,

> Sea `n` un entero positivo o `0`:
>
> ```
> int fila = pos / nCol;
> int columna = pos % nCol;
> ```

La fila será cuántas veces se ha llegado al final de las columnas.
La columna será cuántas posiciones se llevan en esta fila.

Por ello es necesario que la división sea entera.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario. Las posiciones que me genera el Random están en el intervalo [0,191]. En caso de que me de alguna posición de la primera fila, es decir, en [0,11], ¿seguiría funcionando? Y en caso afirmativo, ¿qué me devolvería? Gracias.

Comment: Si devuelve un 11, la fila es 0 (11/12 = 0) y la columna es 11 (11%12 = 11), por lo que la posición es [0, 11].

Comment: Otra forma de generar una posición aleatoria sería generar dos enteros, uno para la fila y otro para la columna. Quizás te resulte un poco más sencillo.

Comment: Lo pensé pero según el enunciado del ejercicio que debo hacer no puedo. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, lo entendí perfectamente :)